# 1-Wire bus implementation in PIC18F series for Parallax ColorPAL #28380 sensors

Tags: microcontroller, pic, parallax, 1-wire

I've bought a Parallax ColorPal 28380 color sensor, 
http://www.parallax.com/Portals/0/Downloads/docs/prod/sens/28380ColorPAL.pdf

In the documentation above, they've used a Basic Stamp microcontroller, and I want to use this sensor with Microchip's 18F (18F2550 or 18F4550) microcontroller series.

The problem that I've been experiencing is, the sensor communicates in 2400-7200 bps range.
I can't use PIC's own UART unit because the sensor has 1 pin only.
First thing that came into my mind is using 1-wire protocol but it is operating at 15400 bps which is too fast.

Now I'm wondering, if I place a diode in front of TX line and merge it with RX line, is this setup works ?
Or is there any way to control the transmission speed of the 1-Wire protocol ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use a UART because it's an Open-Collector interface - the pin used for the serial data should never be driven high. It should be set to tri-stated (high-impedance input) to transmit a "one" bit and set to an output driven low to transmit a "zero" bit, and this data should be sent at a prescribed baud rate. I'm pretty confident that any UART by itself will drive the signal both high and low. So if you want to use a UART to implement this interface, you need to introduce some external hardware. The following circuit is taken from an [Atmel app-note](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2579.pdf&ei=J0VOT9XiIcS7twex3OykCA&usg=AFQjCNH_QXRSZrsRi95-lcTqBHwxpzJM2w):

[image]

I *think* the module you've linked to provides the (equivalent of) the 4.7kOhm pullup, but it's hard to say.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm gonna buy those BC547s first thing tomorrow (its 6pm now) and post results if I succeed. In the meantime, are you familiar with the 1-wire protocol and how to adjust its baud rate ?

Comment: @Ismail I'm not very knowledgable on the PIC18F's capabilities. But if it has one-wire hardware there should be a baud rate register...

Comment: @Ismail Kuruca: Maybe you will find this Microchip App Note helpful. When you are using a simple I/O Pin instead of the usart, you dont need the BC547's ... http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01199a.pdf